# how to read and extract an integer from a string in java

Tags: java

Given a string

```
7 + 45 * 65
```

How to check whether a given character of this string is an integer and then store the whole integer value in an integer variable?

E.g. for 65, check if 6 is an integer, if yes, then store 65 in another integer variable. You can assume that the string can be converted into a character array.

Comment: As Jerry McCoder, Jerry Maguire's cousin, famously said... *Show me the code*!?!?

Comment: His fiance said "You had me at hello world()"

Comment: I'm assuming that this is a programming assignment.  Can you show the code you currently have or the approach you're thinking of (along with concerns), etc?  Are you supposed to go through and compute the value of the expression?  If so, what operators are possible?  Negative numbers?

Comment: Iam not sure, is this an assignment on CFG!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a quick and dirty soluiton I would use StringTokenizer and try { Integer.parseInt() } catch (NumberFormatException){}

Answer (score 3):

Given that this looks like homework below are some tips for a simple way to parse and store each integer value.

- Check out the API documentation for the [`Character`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) class.  This will contain methods for determining whether a character is a digit.
- Consider using a [`StringBuilder`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) to store the intermediate numerical result as you read in each digit of the number.
- Check the [`Integer`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) class API for methods to help with parsing the `String` value (stored within your `StringBuilder`) and turning it into an `int`.
- Finally, consider using a List (e.g. LinkedList) to store the int value.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this post on exactly the same topic:

[Java Programming - Evaluate String math expression](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5144807)

It looks like BeanShell has the cleanest method to do what you need. You could also try the JavaScript Engine method (although BeanShell looks much cleaner to me).

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution would be to use java.util.Scanner. You can set `Scanner.useDelimeter("\\D+")` which will mean skip any non-digit characters, and then call `Scanner.nextInt()` to get next Integer from the String.

If you want to work with characters, then use `Character.isDigit(char c)`.

Comment: Your answer was good but i didnt used it .. but its perfectly right and ill use it in future .. thans